# Lobed Nuclei still count as One nucleus?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, hematology, immune-system, stem-cells

Do the Lobed Nuclei of immune cells (such as Megakaryocytes) still count as one nucleus?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. [Lobation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobation) is when a nucleus deforms, but it is still a single compartment. How the nucleus deforms can be helpful in roughly determining the cell type by visual inspection.

[image]